# Does required on selectOneMenu only accept true?

Tags: java, jsf-2

I have this selectOneMenu that asks for something, the default value is empty, because people need to think about the question and actually needs to fill it in.

```
<h:selectOneMenu id="fileSecurity" value="#{flowScope.application.fileSecurity}" required="true" >  
    <f:selectItem itemLabel="" itemValue="" noSelectionOption="true"/>  
    <f:selectItem itemLabel="ja" itemValue="true" />  
    <f:selectItem itemLabel="nee" itemValue="false" />     
</h:selectOneMenu>
```

This is what i have, now when you fill in the empty value it gives: "managementTabs:ApplicationManagementForm:fileSecurity : Needs to be filled in."
wich is correct.

When i click yes or the true value it accepts the anwser.

But when i click no or false it gives:
"managementTabs:ApplicationManagementForm:fileSecurity: Validation Error: Value is not valid"

- Why does Jsf2.0 only accept true as the valid awnser and not false?
- Is there a way around this? Or do i have to write a custom validator?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It seems that a submitted value of `false` is conflicting with the empty string value of `noSelectionOption` in some way. The following entries for the 1st item works fine:

```xml
<f:selectItem itemLabel="" itemValue="" />
```

and

```xml
<f:selectItem itemLabel="" noSelectionOption="true" />
```

and

```xml
<f:selectItem itemLabel="" itemValue="#{null}" noSelectionOption="true" />
```

I only don't understand why. It's illogical. To find the real answer, I would need to run the debugger.

---

**Update**: I debugged and found the culprit in the `SelectUtils#valueIsNoSelectionOption()` (Mojarra). The empty string of the `noSelectionOption` get coerced to `boolean false` instead of `Boolean null` and hence the comparison with the submitted value is valid and hence the selected value is invalid. This is "by design". You really need to explicitly specify an `itemValue="#{null}"`.

Comment: Thanks for responding, but it's actually the <f:selectItem itemLabel="nee" itemValue="false" /> that doesn't do what it is suposed to. It needs to let me save it and not just give: Value is not valid

Comment: Yes, I've posted an answer to that. Did you for instance try any of them? Did you read the last paragraph of my answer?

Comment: Oooh, no i actually misread your first sentence. I figured you meant that if i add those that the first item would be "valid".

Comment: You're welcome. I have moved the last sentence to top anyway.